# List is not appending

Tags: python-3.x

Thanks for looking into this. I have a project that is basically inventory control of an animal shelter. I'm having issues with my adopt function. I need that function to append to a list and return that list to the main function and it has to repeat itself and update the list if the user decides to adopt multiple times. What my program is doing is overwriting the list everytime the adopt function is run again. Not sure what I'm doing incorrectly

```html
#Steven Phu
#CSC 110, Spring 2017
#Animal Shelter
#This program keeps tracks of animals in an animal shelter. The program will
#access three different list and allows the user to manipulate what happens to
#the animals.


#main program calls upon function get_decision and gets return value of decision. It then runs if statements to see which function is appropriate for the input. While loop keeps running the program until user inputs quit.
#once program is out of while loop, it prints out the counter for each category
def main():
    decision = get_decision()
    adopted_counter = 0 #starting counters for adopted and transferred
    transferred_counter = 0
    pet_list = get_pet("pets.txt")
    while (decision != "quit"):
        elif (decision == "adopt"):
            adopt = do_adopt(pet_list)
            adopted_counter += 1
            print(adopt)
            print()
            decision = get_decision()
    for i in range(0, len(pet_list)):
        current_counter = i
    print(str(current_counter) + " pets currently in the shelter")
    print(str(adopted_counter) + " adopted")
    print(str(transferred_counter) + " transferred")
     
#Lists options of what the user can make and returns their decision to main function
def get_decision():
    print("Welcome to animal shelter management software version 1.0!")
    print("adopt: adopt a pet")
    print("intake: add more animals to the shelter")
    print("list: display all adoptable pets")
    print("quit: exit the program")
    print("save: save the current data")
    print("transfer: transfer pets to another shelter")
    decision = input("option? ")
    while decision != "list" and decision != "adopt" and decision != "save" and decision != "quit" and decision != "transfer" and decision != "intake":
        print("Not a valid option")
        decision = input("option? ")
    return decision

#opens pet file and breaks it down into a parts and puts it all together into a tuples and returns value
def get_pet(file):
    f = open(file)
    pet_info = f.readlines()
    pet = []
    for line in pet_info:
        info = line.split()
        pet_type = info[0]
        name = info[1]
        age = info[2]
        pet.append((name, age, pet_type))
    return pet

def do_adopt(pet_list):
    decision_type = input("cat or dog? ")
    decision_name = input("name? ")
    adopt = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(pet_list):
        if (pet_list[i][2] == decision_type):
            if(pet_list[i][0] == decision_name):
                pet = str(pet_list[i])
                pet_list.pop(i)
                adopt.append(pet)
                return adopt
            else:
                i+=1
        else:
            i+=1
    print("Not found")
    return


main()
```

Comment: There's too much info in this question. Try to reduce the example to one which is minimal, but also exhibits your problem.

Comment: I don't like that `return adopt` line in the `while` cycle, what is the purpose of it? `return <anything>` stops the function execution immediately, this can be the bug you're looking for

Comment: Sorry bout that. I thought more info would be helpful. If i remember correctly, I was having issues with the while loop outputing multiple times and i believe teh return stopped it from doing that. The list does update itself but it just overrides the previous entry

Comment: Learn more about [ask] and creating [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list gets overwritten because you have declared `adopt = []` inside the function `do_adopt` and every time function is called `adopt` gets assigned a new list. A solution to this:

```
pet_list = get_pet("pets.txt")
lst = [] # line to add
while (decision != "quit"):
```

And,

```
adopt = do_adopt(pet_list)
lst.extend(adopt) # line to add
adopted_counter += 1
print(lst) # line to update
```

Comment: oh thank you so much. I not only tried declaring `adopt list` in the function `do adopt` but inside the `while loop` as well. This makes sense. Thank you again